# Apt keeps trying to connect to a non-existent proxy

Tags: networking, apt, proxy

I have an apt proxy on my home network which is running squid-deb-proxy, all my Ubuntu machines are linked to it with a 02proxy file in their apt directorys.

The problem is one of my Ubuntu machines sometimes tries to connect to an IP which doesn't even exist on my network when installing or updating software.

The IP address of my proxy machine is 10.1.1.31 yet the client Ubuntu machine sometimes (not always) tries to connect to 10.1.1.8, I have no idea what's causing it to do this.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, squid-deb-proxy-client was acting extremely weird so I removed it and now it works fine.